# How do I get my Delphi XE5 DataSnap REST server to return XML and not JSON?

Tags: xml, json, delphi, rest, datasnap

I have a working Delphi XE5 DataSnap server up and running but by default it always return JSON.

How can I get the server to return XML formatted results instead of JSON?

I've looked at the TDSServer, TDSHTTPWebDispatcher and TDSServerClass components but I can find no properties that let me select if JSON or XML should be used.

Comment: Probably because DataSnap only supports JSON?

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression from Marco Cantu's technote "REST Servers in Delphi XE Using DataSnap" that it supports both JSON and XML. Quote: "While web services use either XML or JSON, Delphi REST servers default to the latter.". Does "default to the latter" mean that it only supports JSON?

Comment: AFAIK, DataSnap REST is bound to JSON. If you need XML you might have a look at InternetExpress: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Building_an_InternetExpress_Application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return XML, fill the responsecontent directly:

```
uses DBXPlatform;

function TServerMethods1.EchoString(Value: string): string;
var
  metaData: TDSInvocationMetadata;
  i: integer;
begin
  metaData := GetInvocationMetadata;
  for i := 0 to Pred(metaData.QueryParams.Count) do
  begin
    Result := Result + '<param>' + metaData.QueryParams[i] + '</param>';
  end;
  metaData.ResponseContent := '<xml>' + Result + '</xml>';
end;
```